# Check url status in PowerShell version 2

Tags: .net, powershell-2.0

I have the below code to check website status in PowerShell version 2.

```
Begin {
    $webRequest = [Net.WebRequest]::Create("http://webdesa2:2003/Login.aspx");
}
Process {
    try {
        if ((($webRequest.GetResponse()).Statuscode) -as [int] -eq 200) {
            Write-Host "Site is Up";
            $webrequest.GetResponse();
        } else {
            Write-Host -Fore Red "Site is Down"
        }
    } catch {
        Write-Host -Fore Red "Site is Down"
    }
}
```

But I am getting the below output when executing the above code.

> Exception calling "GetResponse" with "0" arguments: "The remote server returned an error: <401> Unauthorized."

This code worked good on websites where authentication is not required. My intention is to check if the site is up or not.

Answer (score 1):

Catch the error and check if the status code is 401.

```
try {
    $response = $webRequest.GetResponse()
    if ($response.StatusCode.value__ -eq 200) {
        Write-Host 'Site is up.'
    } else {
        Write-Host 'Site is down.'
    }
} catch {
    if ($_.Exception.InnerException.Response.StatusCode.value__ -eq 401) {
        Write-Host 'Site is up.'
    } else {
        Write-Host 'Site is down.'
    }
}
```

**Edit:** Simplified code:

```
$validStatus = 200, 401

try {
    $status = $webRequest.GetResponse().StatusCode.value__
} catch {
    $status = $_.Exception.InnerException.Response.StatusCode.value__
}

if ($validStatus -contains $status) {
    Write-Host 'Site is up.'
} else {
    Write-Host 'Site is down.'
}
```